# Phone authentication session control in android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to put (email-id, password), login by otp. In the 1st case, it moves to the other activity through which they have to login after verification of their mail. So here  I am checking by is Email Verified method and if yes then it redirects to home page. In the 2nd case, is there any method like the 1st case for if mobile verified? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase phone auth for your 2nd case,

> You can use Firebase Authentication to sign in a user by sending an SMS message to the user's phone. The user signs in using a one-time code contained in the SMS message.

You can use this once the user is not yet verified through sms, then add flag like 'isMobileVerified' on your database which you'll update after the user has verified via the code sent on his/her number.

[Please see doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

Comment: Can you please help me out that how to test for that user defined function of another activity to the launcher activity please?